# VBA ms word macro: convert an embedded HTML link into plain text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to add a subroutine into my Word 2007 macro that will take the text and address for an embedded link in a document, and convert it to an `href` tag that uses the text as the display text, and the address for the HTML address.

So a line that appears as "go here to get to google" with a blue underline, and when clicked goes to www.google.com, gets replaced with:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">go here to get to google</a>
```

This routine is to be added to an existing macro that I already have that does some other minor formatting, so no need for headers and whatnot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print the HTML tags as you specify for all of the links in your document.

```
Dim hlink As Hyperlink
Dim htmlLink As String

For Each hlink In ThisDocument.Hyperlinks
    With hlink
        htmlLink = "<a target=""_blank"" href=""" & .Address & """>" & _
            .TextToDisplay & "</a>"

        Debug.Print htmlLink
    End With
Next hlink
```

Of course, you'll want to do something more useful with them than just print them in the Immediate window.

As an aside, I prefer to use [DuckDuckGo](http://duckduckgo.com/) in my examples due its much better [privacy policy](https://duckduckgo.com/privacy.html) than Google's...

Comment: Ah thanks!  And point well made on duckduckgo, I hadn't even considered using a more intelligent choice on my random webpage (usually use hp.com as its only 2 letters, but I stopped myself as I don't really like their er, stuff.)